# can I format a disk under existing window 8 and install ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

My laptop is currently installed with windows 8, and it has 4 disks, C D E F.

Now I want to install ubuntu, can I format F disk and install ubuntu with the formatted space? is so, what are the procedures?

thanks!

Comment: Try this (go just past #3 to be where you are) http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

When you choose to install Ubuntu it should ask you how you want to install it, and one of the options is 'alongside Windows'. It should give you the option to choose a partition and resize it if you like.